# Jquery - :Contains case insensitive

Tags: jquery, filter, contains, case-insensitive

I've read lots of suggestions on how to make contains case insensitive, but none seem to fit with what I've got.  Sorry if I've missed the obvious.

I've got this.

```
var data = this.value.split(" ");
        $.each(data, function(i, v) {
            rows.filter(":contains('" + v + "')").show();
        });
```

How do I make it case insensitive ?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I've got this working using:

```
var data = this.value.split(" ");
    $.each(data, function(i, v) {
        rows.filter(":Contains('" + v + "')").show();
    });
});

jQuery.expr[":"].Contains = jQuery.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
return function( elem ) {
    return jQuery(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};
```

Comment: What is `rows`? Can you give an example of what is in `data`?

Comment: Hi this is what i'm working with : `http://jsfiddle.net/cpt43b9j/`  it works fine but isn't case insensitive.

Comment: Can you explain why this is a duplicate ? I've explained what I'm trying to do and that I can't seem to get it to fit with what I've read.  Thx